# Regex match contingent non word in string

Tags: regex

How would I create a regex which matches all contingent non words "[a].[b]" in a string? I don't care about spaces or newline or any invisible character I haven't heard about, as long as it only matches the contingent string. Anything else is invalid.

```
[a].[b] // valid for "[a].[b]"
 [a].[b] // valid for "[a].[b]"
[a].[b]  // valid for "[a].[b]"
\n[a].[b] // valid for "[a].[b]"

[a].[b]$[c] // invalid because of "$" (or any other character) and everything after
[c]$[a].[b] // invalid because of "$" (or any other character) and everything before
[c].[a].[b] // invalid because of "[c]."
```

The problem I'm having is if I try

```
[\ \n\r]
```

it matches the space before " [a].[b]" which is not what I want, I want spaces to be ignored because I don't want to replace anything besides "[a].[b]". But of course only when it is a contingent string, "somethinganythingbutspaceandnewline[a].[b]" I don't want to replace.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like `\A\s*\[a\]\.\[b\]\s*\Z`?

Comment: if [a].[b] is valid then why [c].[a].[b] is invalid ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman because I only want the contingent string of "[a].[b]" so if ANYTHING besides spaces is next to those the contingent string is no longer "[a].[b]".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want `[a].[b]` string with possible *leading* and *trailing* whitespaces. If it's your case, I suggest `\A\s*\[a\]\.\[b\]\s*\Z` pattern, e.g. (**C#** code)

```
  string pattern = @"\A\s*\[a\]\.\[b\]\s*\Z";

  string source = "\n[a].[b] \t  ";

  if (Regex.IsMatch(source, pattern))
    Console.Write("Match");
  else 
    Console.Write("Not Match");
```

Pattern:

```
 \A           - beginning of the text 
 \s*          - zero or more leading whitespaces
 \[a\]\.\[b\] - string to find (please, notice escapements)
 \s*          - zero or more trailing whitespaces
 \Z           - end of the text
```

**Edit:** As far as I can see, the match's core is a constant - `[a].[b]`, so I doubt if you really want the match's text which is `"[a].[b]"`. If you do 
you can try *look ahead* and *look behind* construction (**C#** code):

```
 string pattern = @"(?<=\A\s*)\[a\]\.\[b\](?=\s*\Z)";

 string source = "\n[a].[b] \t  ";  

 var match = Regex.Match(source, pattern);

 if (match.Success)
   Console.Write($"Matched: '{match.Value}'");
```

Now

```
 (?<=\A\s*) - zero or more leading spaces should be matched but not included into the match
 (?=\s*\Z) - zero or more trailing spaces should be matched but not included into the match
```

**Edit 2**: in case you have *several* `[a].[b]` separated by white spaces (see comments below)

```
  string pattern = @"(?<=\A|\s+)\[a\]\.\[b\](?=\s+|\Z)";

  string source = "[a].[b]  [a].[b][a].[b] [a].[b] \t ";

  string result = string.Join(", ", Regex
    .Matches(source, pattern)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value));

  Console.Write(join);
```

Outcome (2 matches):

```
  [a].[b], [a].[b]
```

Comment: If you know, why [c].[a].[b] is invalid but [a].[b] is valid ?

Comment: @Rizwan M.Tuman: As far as I've understood the question (from the examples provided) the match is `[a].[b]` fragment with possible leading and trailing whitespaces

Comment: Well what confuses me is the reasoning of the last line  // invalid because of "."

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you, running this through https://regex101.com/ however gives me a full match for " [a].[b] ". I don't want to replace the spaces, is it possible to remove those from the match?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you again! This is a great step in the right direction, thank you! Just one more thing like I said in my original post I need all of the "[a].[b]" in a string, so if I have "[a].[b] [a].[b]" I want the result you showed how to get. Unfortunately I get nothing with that test string. Is that possible?

Comment: @bdebaere: How many matches do you want to have in case of `"[a].[b]  [a].[b]  [a].[b][a].[b]"`? *four* (per each `"[a].[b]"`) or just **one**?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko "[a].[b] [a].[b] [a].[b][a].[b]" would yield 2 matches: the first two would match because they can be seen as two pieces of "[a].[b]". The last two wouldn't because it is no longer "[a].[b]" but "[a].[b][a].[b]" consecutively. Because there are no spaces they hang together.